# Vector space decomposed by operator $T$ such that $T^2=I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that $T^2$ is the identity operator. Prove that for any $v\in V$, $v-T(v)$ is either $0_V$ or is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. Prove that $V=V(1)\oplus V(-1)$.

*$V(\lambda)$ denotes eigenspace

I have no problem showing that $v-T(v)$ is either $0_V$ or is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. From this we see that $v\in V(1)$ or $v-T(v)\in V(-1)$ for every $v\in V$.

Also, no problem showing that $V(1)$ and $V(-1)$ are independent. However, I am stuck on showing that $V=V(1)+V(-1)$. So far:

We know that either $v\in V(1)$ or $v\notin V(1)$. If the former, then $v=v+0\in V(1)+V(-1)$. If $v\notin V(1)$, then we know that $v-T(v)\in V(-1)$. Then we could write
$$
v = T(v)+v-T(v),
$$
and if $T(v)\in V(1)$, then we are done. But I haven't been able to prove nor disprove $T(v)\in V(1)$.

Am I on the right track? I feel like I am missing something completely obvious. Somehow I think I should use that $T$ is invertible, and hence has trivial kernel, but I do not see how.

And I would love to see different solutions for this problem, if they exist.

Comment: @Martin Argerami: I originally thought the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I make that mistake often. Look at the edit now.

Comment: Note that one needs the field of scalars to have characteristic different from $2$ for this to hold.  Pedro Tamaroff's answer gives an indication of why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $T^2=I$ we have that $m_T\mid (X-1)(X+1)$. By what your wrote, you seem to have assumed $T\neq -{\rm id},\rm id$. Thus $m_T=(X-1)(X+1)$.  It follows $T$ is diagonalizable. Since the only eigenvalues of $T$ are $1,-1$, we have that $V=V(1)\oplus V(-1)$, for

> **THM** A transformation $T:V\to V$ over a finite dimensional vector space is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial factors linearly, and all its roots are simple, iff $V=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^r V(\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i;i=1,2,\ldots,r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

The proof is not too complicated, but we can use it for your special case. Since $\gcd(X-1,X+1)=1$, we know we can write $$\frac 1 2 (X+1)-\frac 1 2 (X-1)=1$$

It follows that, for any $v\in V$, $$\frac 1 2 (T+1)v-\frac 1 2 (T-1)v=v$$

**ADD** Careful! As Marc has noted, if $2=0$ in $K$, we're in trouble. See his answer.

Now, note that $(T+1)(T-1)v=0$ for *any* $v$. It follows that the first term is in $V(-1)$ and the second term is in $V(1)$. Hence $V=V(1)\oplus V(-1)$.

---

**PROOF** (of the theorem)

We use that if $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $T\in{\rm end}\; V$ then $m_V={\rm lcm}(m_{v_1},\ldots,m_{v_n})$ where $m_{v_i}$ denotes the minimal polynomial of the vector $v_i$. If $T$ is diagonalizable, then it admits a basis  $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of eigenvectors. It is immediate $m_{v_{i_j}}=X-\lambda_{i_j}$, where $\lambda_{i_j}$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. Thus $m_T={\rm lcm}(m_{v_1},\ldots,m_{v_n})=(X-\lambda_1)\cdots (X-\lambda_r)$ where $\lambda_i:i=1,2,\ldots,r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$. Suppose conversely that $m_A=(X-\lambda_1)\cdots (X-\lambda_r)$. Since $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$ for $i\neq j$,  the polynomials $P_j=\prod_{i\neq j}(X-\lambda_i)$ are all coprime in pairs. Writing $$1=P_1Q_1+\cdots+P_rQ_r$$ we will have for any $v$ that $$v=P_1(T)Q_1(T)v+\cdots+P_r(T)Q_r(T)v$$

But $w_i=P_i(T)Q_i(T)v$ is in $V(\lambda_i)$, for $(X-\lambda_i)P_i=m_T$ by construction. This means  $V=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^r V(\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i;i=1,2,\ldots,r$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$, so $T$ is diagonalizable. $\blacktriangleleft$

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I think it is way too complicated for this (very simple!) problem.

Comment: I appreciate it, though. It motivates Martin's answer for me!

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: What is the vertical bar in $m_T|(X-1)(X+1)$? I have not seen that notation before.

Comment: @PaulElfish It means "divides". At any rate, you can focus on what comes after the theorem. That's the "key" idea behind it all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Agreed, but as always I think that it helps other people, and it will eventually be of value to Paul.

Comment: I agree: Pedro's answer identifies the OP's question as a simple special case of a very important more general fact.  As a complement to Martin's answer, it should be very useful.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the comment. =)

Comment: Ah, that's a valid point. Even so, to me at least, it is more that the simple special case motivates the more general and abstract than the other way around. But even from that point of view, I must agree that your answer is useful. I am glad it is not the *only* answer provided, though. (Now adding my own upvote …) ☺

Answer (score 6):

Somehow the naive way seems to fail. Looking at the example $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, the following decomposition seems to be the right one:
$$
v=\frac{v+Tv}2+\frac{v-Tv}2.
$$
The first term is an eigenvector for $1$ and the second one for $-1$.

Comment: This is the right way. To rephrase: $\frac12(I+T)$ and $\frac12(I-T)$ are projections (operators $P$ with $P^2=P$) with sum $I$. Their images are the two eigenspaces in question.

Comment: (In fact, that is the right decomposition for any such $T$, provided that $m_T=(X-1)(X+1)$. See my answer)

Comment: @Harald: thanks. That point of view should be way more familiar to me, but somehow I didn't see it. Nice.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using $v=T(v)+(v-T(v))$ you should try to use $2v=(v+T(v))+(v-T(v))$, and then show $v+T(v)\in V(1)$, which is easy. Then you know that $2v\in V(1)+V(-1)$, and if your field is not of characteristic$~2$ you can divide by$~2$ to conclude that $v\in V(v)+V(-1)$ as well. If you do have a field of characteristic$~2$ then you are out of luck, and the property you are trying to prove is actually false. But since you already showed that $V(1)$ and $V(-1)$ are "independent" (you must have meant that they form a direct sum), you must have been (implicitly) using that the field is not of characteristic$~2$, since if it were then $V(1)=V(-1)$ and their sum will *not* be direct.

Summary: in characteristic other than$~2$ the sum is direct and equal to the whole space as desired; in characteristic$~2$ the sum is neither direct nor fills the whole space.